# Biblatex custom cite macro

Tags: macros, biblatex, citing

I don't really understand how to use macros, but this would be a good way to learn.
Currently, I simply use `\cite`, which prints Author, Year. When I have this in a sentence, I want the year to be in brackets, so it looks like Author (Year),

I can do this manually with

```
\citeauthor{author} (\citeyear{author}), conducted a detailed study on different methods of...
```

But this would be a drag to type out every time. How would I create a macro such as `\citeintext{author}` that would do all that for me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Wouldn't `\textcite{author} conducted ...` be what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, yes it would be -facepalm-
Thanks, I really am new to this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the basic author-year style, there are two main commands:

```
\textcite{key}
\parencite{key}
```

The former is for textual citations, the latter for parenthetical ones:

```
... as we see in the fundamental book by \textcite{key1}. Some developments
have appeared recently \parencite{key2}.
```

will appear something like

> … as we see in the fundamental book by Author (1990). Some developments
>   have appeared recently (Scholar, 2012).

Comment: There's also the higher-level command `\autocite` which maps to `\parencite` for author-year-styles.